# Hide element using CSS3

Tags: javascript, css

Are their ways to hide the `strong` tags if there are no `ul`s using only CSS

```
<div class="lower lts-blue">    
    <strong>Interest Focus</strong>:
    <br/>

    <strong>Skills</strong>:
    <ul id="dnn_ctr2446_View_blSkills" class="tags">
        <li><a href="">Observing</a></li><li><a href="">Comparing &amp; Contrasting</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br/>

    <strong>Type</strong>: 
    <ul id="dnn_ctr2446_View_blType" class="tags">
        <li><a href="">Exemplars</a></li>
    </ul>        
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify "ul element don't have child is CSS"?

Comment: @WilliamYang They mean when the tag is empty; `<ul></ul>` vs `<ul><li></li></ul>`.

Comment: no. see the html tag<strong>Interest Focus</strong> it dosn't have ul child because of the it should me hide

Comment: There is no pure CSS way to do this logic currently. But if you had a way to select the preceding sibling you would be able to achieve this buy selecting the `strong` element as the preceding sibling of the `ul` and set it's display accordingly - that way the `strong` el will display only if a sibling `ul` el exists. Unfortunately, this is not yet supported. Hopefully we'll see it happen in CSS4 though, there has already been requests: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Feb/0279.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
div.lower > strong{
     display: none; /* or visibility: hidden; */
}
```

The `>` selector used to select the direct child. if the div has a direct child which is `strong` then that element will be hidden but not the `strong` element which is inside the `ul` tag.

For more information, have a look at this [**link**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).

**Update**:

If you want to hide the `strong` element if there are no `ul` tags in the `div` then it can be done dynamically using javascript.

*Javascript*

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('lower')[0];
var ul = div.getElementsByTagName('ul');
var strong = div.getElementsByTagName('strong');
if(!ul[0]){
    for(var i=0; i < strong.length; i++){
        strong[i].className += " dynamicStrong";
    }
}
```

*CSS*

```
.dynamicStrong{
     display: none; /* or visibility: hidden; */
}
```

In above code, I added a class `dynamicStrong` to the `strong` element if and only if there are no `ul` tags in the `div` element.

The check for whether there are `ul` tags in `div`  is done by using `if(!ul[0])` in javacript code.

You can also add a inline style using javascript in the for loop,

```
strong[i].style.display = "none";
```

I don't like the above approach because it creates a inline styling to that specified element and also overrides the previous css properties.

Comment: @apaul34208 I suppose OP wants the same. if the `strong` is inside `ul` theen it should be visible and if the `strong` is direct child of the `div` then it should be hidden. isn't it?